# Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException: Invalid XML file 0.1.0 Payeezy Magento 2

Tags: magento2, xml

```
Facing below error:

>Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException: Invalid XML in file 0.1.0 Payeezy_PayeezyCheckout_Model payeezycheckout_mysql4 Payeezy_PayeezyCheckout_Model_Mysql4 payeezycheckout_api_debug
Payeezy_PayeezyCheckout_Helper Payeezy_PayeezyCheckout Payeezy_PayeezyCheckout_Model_Mysql4_Setup core_setup core_write core_read Payeezy_PayeezyCheckout_Block /payeezycheckout/shared standard Payeezy_PayeezyCheckout payeezycheckout Payeezy_PayeezyCheckout.csv payeezycheckout.xml Payeezy_PayeezyCheckout.csv USD payeezycheckout/shared PUT SECRET WORD HERE 1 redirect 0 processing holded pending canceled canceled canceled 0 : Element 'modules': This element is not expected. Expected is one of ( default, stores, websites ). Line: 3 in /home/dukaania/public_html/testing2/app/code/MageBig/MbFrame/Framework/App/Config/Initial/Reader.php:129 Stack trace: #0 /home/dukaania/public_html/testing2/generated/code/MageBig/MbFrame/Framework/App/Config/Initial/Reader/Proxy.php(95): MageBig\MbFrame\Framework\App\Config\Initial\Reader->read() #1 /home/dukaania/public_html/testing2/app/code/MageBig/MbFrame/Framework/App/Config/Initial.php(58): MageBig\MbFrame\Framework\App\Config\Initial\Reader\Proxy->read() #2 /home/dukaania/public_html/testing2/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(111): MageBig\MbFrame\Framework\App\Config\Initial->__construct(Object(MageBig\MbFrame\Framework\App\Config\ThemeId), Object(MageBig\MbFrame\Framework\App\Config\Initial\Reader\Proxy), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Cache\Type\Config), NULL) #3 /home/dukaania/public_html/testing2/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(66): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->createObject('MageBig\\MbFrame...', Array) #4 

Here's my xml code:

                <?xml version="1.0"?>
            <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Module/etc/module.xsd">
                   <modules>
                      <Payeezy_PayeezyCheckout>
                    <active>true</active>
                   <codePool>local</codePool>
                <depends>
                       <Mage_Payment/>
                   </depends>
            </Payeezy_PayeezyCheckout>
       </modules>
    </config>
```

Comment: magento 2 plss...

Comment: I post the answer, if you are asking for magento-2, then you need to put code into module.xml file not the config.xml file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For magento2, you need to put the code into the module.xml file available into this place.

app\code\Payeezy\PayeezyCheckout\etc\module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Payeezy_PayeezyCheckout" setup_version="1.0.0" schema_version="1.0.0">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Payment"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```